# Error when connecting to MongoDb Atlas Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongodb-atlas

I'm getting an AtlasError with code 8000, based on the MongoServerError 'bad auth: Authentication failed'

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you supplying your credentials and establishing the connection? Please add anonymized code to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix: 'MongoError: authentication fail' @MongoDB Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882959/how-to-fix-mongoerror-authentication-fail-mongodb-atlas)

Answer (score 1):

While you are copying url from atlas, you have to put your own password in the code too, I think because you haven't put password or it's wrong password that's why this error is happening